# How to show header in Log out put from log4j?

Tags: java, spring, log4j, logback, log4j2

I need to show project version at the top followed by project logs in log output.

like this,

```
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
18:02:33.407 [main] DEBUG c.j.e.l.App - Starting debugging
18:02:33.410 [main] INFO  c.j.e.l.b.Message - The message is: Hello World!
18:02:33.410 [main] INFO  c.j.e.l.b.Message - The message is: Hello World!
18:02:33.412 [main] DEBUG c.j.e.l.App - Ending debugging
```

But I couldn't do that header part.

Please subject me for showing my project version in header.

This is my logback.xml content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <!-- Send debug messages to System.out -->
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <!-- By default, encoders are assigned the type ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder -->

        <encoder>
        <pattern >%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{5} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.javacodegeeks.examples.logbackmavenexample.beans" level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </logger>

    <!-- By default, the level of the root level is set to DEBUG -->
    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

And this is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.javacodegeeks.examples</groupId>
    <artifactId>logbackmavenexample</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>logbackmavenexample</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
        <logback.version>1.1.2</logback.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <slf4j-api.version>1.7.7</slf4j-api.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- SLF4J - API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- logback -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JUnit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>*</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Please subject me to show the project version at the top of my log output

Comment: You want to show project version once, in the beginning of log file? or what?

Comment: @Nikolay Yes I want to show project version at the beginning of log

Answer (score 0):

I updated my answer.

Use the maven-jar-plugin to put your project.version to the builded jar's MANIFEST.MF. So put this lines to maven plugins:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                </manifest>
            </archive>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

This will result (among others) the following entry in the Manifest:

```
Implementation-Version: 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

You can read it with the following code:

```
package com.javacodegeeks.examples.logbackmavenexample.beans;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.jar.Attributes;
import java.util.jar.JarFile;
import java.util.jar.Manifest;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class MyBean {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyBean.class);

    public static String getManifestInfo() {

        try {
            // reading all MANIFEST.MF from the classpath: from every jar/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF and every folder/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF and search for ours
            Enumeration<URL> resEnum = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
                    .getResources(JarFile.MANIFEST_NAME);
            while (resEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
                try {
                    URL url = resEnum.nextElement();
                    InputStream is = url.openStream();
                    if (is != null) {
                        Manifest manifest = new Manifest(is);
                        Attributes mainAttribs = manifest.getMainAttributes();
                        // artifactId will be mapped to Implementation-Title
                        // so we can use it to identify our manifest file
                        if (!"logbackmavenexample".equals(mainAttribs.getValue("Implementation-Title"))) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        // found! return the version
                        String version = mainAttribs.getValue("Implementation-Version");
                        if (version != null) {
                            return version;
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // Silently ignore wrong manifests on classpath?
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // Silently ignore wrong manifests on classpath?
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LOGGER.info("{} started", MyBean.class.getName());
        // to print out the version ONLY without timestamp, classname, etc. I suggest to use sysout
        System.out.println(getManifestInfo());
        // however I would use this form:
        LOGGER.info("Version: {}", getManifestInfo());
    }
}
```

I modified a bit your logback.xml (I added **additivity="false"** to prevent duplicated log lines when this logger and root logger are active at the same time):

```
<logger name="com.javacodegeeks.examples.logbackmavenexample.beans" level="INFO" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</logger>
```

The other thing I noticed that you have specified a higher log level (INFO) here than in the root logger (there you specified DEBUG). This resulted that my first try logged nothing because I used DEBUG level at calling the specified logger in MyBean. This usually configured inversely, we want everything to log INFO only, and some specific (under development/critical parts) packages are logs with DEBUG/TRACE etc.

Comment: I need to use logback.xml to show project version. So how to access project version (pom.xml) in logback.xml.

Comment: your project.version from pom.xml will be written to the MANIFEST.MF of the created jar/war. You can read it out from there. However, by default AFAIK the project pom packed to the jar/war into the META-INF folder (or, its better to say, in a subfolder, where you can find the MANIFEST.MF btw) too. You can access these files similarly to other resources, or for Manifest, there are some libraries that can be used too. After you read the project version (Implementation-Version entry!), you can do what you want with it.

Comment: logback.xml is for controlling your logging, your project version should not be there, is does not make sense. What you can do is to specify some appenders and loggers there, and you can use one of them to write the fetched version info to the desired/configured appender.

Comment: Can u please give an example. I m new to logback